# Android wait for person to say word?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I'm trying to make a voice recognition app that listens and alerts you right when a specific word is said. All I've seen online is starting and stopping the recognition, then parsing the results. Is there a way to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: try while loop and if your result matches then break.

Comment: You can spot for keyphrase with pocketsphinx, see pocketsphinx android demo. http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid